# ¿Comó extraigo el largo de un array en con vue.js?

Tags: javascript, array, vue.js

Quiero poder extraer el largo del array. En javascript tengo entendido que se hace con `.lenght`, pero no se si en vue.js es diferente; ya que intento y no me funciona.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: es exactamente igual.. dentro de los metodos de vue, se programa en js...

Comment: Si no funciona, podrias contarnos que error recibis? seguramente en la consola tira algun error. Lo que si veo es que estas pidiendo el tamaño de indice, y tu array se llama array?

Answer (score 3):

El problema es que estas intentando acceder a una propiedad que no tienes en tu caso dentro de `data` lo que tienes es `array`, por tanto para saber su largo
debes decir:

```
return this.array.length;
```

Y no:

```
return this.indice.length;
```

Que es como lo tienes implementado hasta ahora, o simplemente cambia

```
data: {
  array: [/*Lo que va adentro*/]
}
```

Por:

```
data: {
  indice: [/*Lo que va adentro*/]
}
```

Y ya puedes acceder con `this.indice.length`

El comentario que puse dentro del arreglo es para que sepas que eso se mantiene solo debes llenarlo con tus valores.

Answer (score 0):

**Te dejo este ejemplo para darte una guia; te comentaré un par de cosas al respecto**

1. En la clave data tienes declarado un arreglo; todo esto al mismo nivel de la instancia de Vue que recién haz creado una vez que escribes `new Vue({})`
2. Cuando intentas desde methods acceder a dicho valor debes hacerlo a través de `this`, para hacer referencia al contexto de la instancia de vue que tienes declarada
3. Para acceder a la longitud o algún otro atributo del array debes hacer por medio de `this.nombreArreglo` donde de forma explicita y clara colocas el nombre del arreglo declarado arriba en data
4. Para fines ilustrativos yo solo coloque que en el evento click del button, se ejecute el método `contar()` que a su vez me retorna la longitud del arreglo

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>JS Bin</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="app">
        <button  v-on:click="contar()">Contar</button>
      </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
    <script>
      let app = new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data:{
        objetos: ["uno", "dos", "tres"]
      },
      methods: {
        contar: function(){
          console.log(this.objetos.length)
        }
      }
    })
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

> Haciendo la aclaración que no es una tarea de VueJS si no una tarea de
>   JavaScript en este caso

Aunque también es posible si la instancia de Vue la asignaste a una variable

En lugar de esto

```
this.arreglo.length
```

hacer esto

```
app.arreglo.length
```

> Entiendiendo que app es la variable a la cual en mi ejemplo asigne la
>   instancia de Vue

**O bien dejarlo de este modo donde accedemos mediante la variable `app` a la instancia recién creada de VueJS**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app">
    <button  @click="contar()">Contar</button>
  </div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
<script>
  let app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data:{
    objetos: ["uno", "dos", "tres"]
  },
  methods: {
    contar(){
      console.log(app.objetos.length)
    }
  }
})
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

En mi caso estaba tratando de realizar una validación de comparación con

```
this.array.length == 0
```

Sin embargo, en mi caso, aunque debía funcionar este código, el tema era que mi arreglo estaba establecido en `null`, por lo que esa validación en mi caso puntual no funcionaba directamente. Primero debía asegurarme que no estuviera en null la variable del arreglo y luego sí proceder a validar el largo. Para este caso, mi solución fue validar en su lugar con `undefined`.

Ejemplo del caso puntual:

```
<template v-if="this.array != undefined">
...
</template>
```